# Yii2 : AuthClinet + Facebook login

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-authclient

i've create a Facebook login app and it works fine when it on localhost but when I published  it online it gives me an error :

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

i've update the app setting to be :

```
App Domains : *******.com
```

and also

```
Site URL :https://********.com/
```

and in Facebook login app setting is

```
Client OAuth Login : No
```

but error still appears